# Sending JSON and parsing it in DB2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I have researched and couldn't find possible solutions.Is it possible to send JSON as input to DB2 stored procedure. If yes can you point me to an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that I found. It says that

`DB2 JSON is a driver-based solution available with DB2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows 10.5 and with the IBM DB2 Accessories Suite V3.1 to work with DB2 on z/OS V10. It facilitates using DB2 as a JSON document store`

and gives steps how to prepare the environment

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1306nosqlforjson4/